# Google/Facebook oauth works in dev but not in prod

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, yii2, google-oauth

I implemented google and facebook oauth on my website. Everything worked fine and then yesterday I've noticed that it doesn't work anymore. I have not change anything in the google and facebook console and I don't remember changing codes related to that lately. Both google and facebook returns the same error.

I've tested Google oauth on my localhost and it works, but not in production.

The google login window appears and I can login correctly but my code crashes when google redirects me to my website.

I've notice that the variable $http_response_header has 14 headers in dev but is empty in prod. It seems to be the source of the problem but I don't know why nor how to debug it.

I'm using the Yii2 framework and the code that crashes is part of the framework.

See the call stack below (it's not complete).

```
   TypeError

   Argument 2 passed to yii\httpclient\Client::createResponse() must be of 
   the type array, null given, called in /home/folder/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-
   httpclient/StreamTransport.php on line 73
   1. in /home/folder/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/Client.php at line 
   200
       return Yii::createObject($config);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a response instance.
     * @param string $content raw content
     * @param array $headers headers list.
     * @return Response request instance.
     */
    public function createResponse($content = null, array $headers = [])
    {
        $config = $this->responseConfig;
        if (!isset($config['class'])) {
            $config['class'] = Response::className();
        }
        $config['client'] = $this;
        $response = Yii::createObject($config);
        $response->setContent($content);
        $response->setHeaders($headers);
    2. in /home/folder/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-httpclient/StreamTransport.php 
    at line 73 – yii\httpclient\Client::createResponse(false, null)
       Yii::endProfile($token, __METHOD__);
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }

        Yii::endProfile($token, __METHOD__);

      $response = $request->client->createResponse($responseContent, 
    $responseHeaders);

        $request->afterSend($response);

        return $response;
    }
```

Can someone help me I don't know where to start and I don't know how to debug this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the -1 but anyway I found the problem.

The php variable "allow_url_fopen" setting was disabled and it must be activated. I didn't change it, something happened on the host.